# Peek & pop previewing on MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapkit, ios9

Has anyone figured out a sane way to do peek and pop previewing on MKMapViews where force-touching on a map annotation peeks a detail view controller?

In `func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?`, I'm getting stuck on getting an annotation out of the map view given the location of the force touch.

EDIT:

OK, getting the annotation for the touch point has now been solved, now  running up against a different issue. Peek and pop on map view is now working, though it fails a significant portion of the time. During the failures, I've confirmed that I'm returning a valid view controller from `func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?`. Anyone else seeing this?

Seems to be related to scrolling, though mucking around with scrollEnabled, etc doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: How did you get to annotation from the touch location?